Concise logic expression in Excel
SAMPLE TABLE
| TABLE | USER |
|  A    | Tim  |
|  A    | John |
|  A    |      |
|  A    | Sim  |
|  B    | Gimmy|
|  B    |      |
|  C    |      |

SUMARRY TABLE
 TABLE | Occupy | Vacant         
    A  | 3      | 1
    B  | 1      | 1
    C  | 0      | 1

I know that it can be done with macro coding using while loop, if-else and count. But I believe the excel function is sufficient for this job. Now I'm just relying on the function below:
Occupy- =COUNTIF(B2:B5,"<>"&"")
Vacant- =COUNTIF(B2:B5,"=")

So basically I have to manually drag the column range for the count function to tally the value for each table category. So the table A starts from B2:B5, B starts from B6:B7 and C starts from B8:B8 My idea for the summary table is that each table category should lookup to the same category table in the sample table and manage the count.
How should I approach this?

You may try PIVOTBY().
=PIVOTBY(A2:A8,MAP(B2:B8,LAMBDA(x,IF(x<>"","Occupied","Vacant"))),B2:B8,COUNTA,0,0,,0)



Beautiful work.

@Michal Thank you! I have learned so many things from StackOverflow. Excellent platform.

Nice use of Pivotby. I believe you don't need the Map though, and could just use =PIVOTBY(A2:A8,IF(B2:B8="","Vacant","Occupied"),B2:B8,COUNTA,0,0,,0)

@TomSharpe You are correct. Formula will be more simpler. Thanks for pointing it.

You can do this easily with the following formulas
D2  =UNIQUE(A2:A8)
E2  =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,D2#,B2:B8,"<>")
F2  =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,D2#)-E2#


What is the meaning of "#" behind the character?

@user234568 - it's called a spill range https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-spill-range/  If you have Excel 365, please see my suggestion below for a single formula solution

Assuming you have Excel 365:
=LET(
    data, A2:B8,
    tables, INDEX(data,,1),
    users, INDEX(data,,2),
    uniqueTables, UNIQUE(tables),

    occupyCount, MAP(uniqueTables, LAMBDA(tbl, SUM((tables=tbl) * (users<>"")))),
    vacantCount,  MAP(uniqueTables, LAMBDA(tbl, SUM((tables=tbl) * (users="")))),

    HSTACK(uniqueTables,occupyCount,vacantCount)
)



Checking for non-blank with wildcard COUNTIFS(table, table, user, "?*"):
=LET(
    table, A2:A8,
    user, B2:B8,
    occupied, COUNTIFS(table, table, user, "?*"),
    UNIQUE(
        HSTACK(table, occupied, COUNTIFS(table, table) - occupied)
    )
)


